# Como escribir todo el contenido de un objeto en una GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Mi problema es el siguiente, deseo pasar todo los datos que recibo y imprimirlos en una Grilla, pasare imágenes para que vean los datos y entiendan mejor mi problema

[image: Datos que deseo1][image: Datos que deseo2][image: Datos que solo me muestra primeros 5]

Esos son datos que deseo y la 3 es lo único que me muestra ,

Como hago para que me muestre todo lo que pueda no solo de unS, si no tambien de unE y unT junto con lo de unS

No se fijen en la Label la puse para verificar que llegan los datos correctamente

Aqui el codigo por si les sirve:

````
    {
        this.MuestroBotones();
        gvSolicitudes.Visible = true;
        try
        {
            //EntidadesCompartidas.Solicitud unS = Logica.LogicaSolicitud.ConsultaEstadoSolicitud(Convert.ToInt32(gvTramites .SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text));
            EntidadesCompartidas.Solicitud unS = Logica.LogicaSolicitud.ConsultaEstadoSolicitud2(Convert.ToInt32(gvTramites.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text), Convert.ToString(gvTramites.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text));
             
            if (unS != null)
            {

                List<EntidadesCompartidas.Solicitud> _lista = LogicaSolicitud.ListarSolicitud(unS);

                gvSolicitudes.DataSource = _lista;
                gvSolicitudes.DataBind();

                lblerror.Text = unS.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                gvSolicitudes.DataSource = null;
                gvSolicitudes.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblerror.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }```
````

Como le digo que quiero escribir mas datos?  Debo hacer la grilla manual?
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Creo que debes de reformular tu pregunta. ¿Qué es unE y unT? Supongo que haces varias consultas (unS, unE, unT) y quieres mostrarlas pero ¿cuántas haces? ¿en dónde las haces? En el código que muestras solo se ve que agregas un elemento a la _lista por lo que solo se muestra ese elemento. Además lo agregas con lógica que no conocemos cómo funciona (Logica.ListarSolicitud)

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi por el reetiquetaje. Lo que yo sugería es que se creara el sinónimo, para que no reaparezca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta estaba en la GridView, debia poner en la grilla en la para de DataField UnE.UnT.Codigo para el codigo, UnE.Cedula para la cedula